# Laravel 5 Route

Tags: laravel, indexing, routes

I did this command

```
php artisan make:controller BrandController
```

I added thefollowing  line of code in the routes.php file

```
Route::resource('admin/brands', 'BrandController');
```

All the methods in the controller get fired except for the index()

I checked the routes list and it is there

```
URI                   Name                   Action                   
admin/brands          admin.brands.index     App\Http\Controllers\BrandController@index
```

I have no idea and have looked and looked and looked but cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had also added the Route

```
Route::resource('admin', 'ProductController');
```

when it should have been

```
Route::resource('admin/products', 'ProductController');
```

Took me over an hour to spot it. I am going to get some sleep